# Random Godot beginner-question: make nodes in group unpickable

Tags: input, godot

`get_node("Area2D").input_pickable = false` works.

`get_tree().get_nodes_in_group("all-area2d-nodes").input_pickable = false` doesn't.

How can I make such a group (un)pickable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this

```
for node in get_tree().get_nodes_in_group("all-area2d-nodes"):
    node.input_pickable = false
```

It`s because this function returns array list.
You need to cycle through the list and set input_pickable for each item separately.

[Official Documentation](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_scenetree.html#class-scenetree-method-get-nodes-in-group)

Comment: Thank you, that's it. The sequence "for node in..." and then "node.input..." is the sticking point here. obviously.
One of the many cases where the docs show me the "what" while leaving me with no idea about the "how"...